# Button to change the language Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, internationalization

I am building an app in Flutter, so far I am using the Internationalization with JSON where the language of the app is based on the language that the user has as default in his phone its working pretty well, but I would like to give the user a chance to change the language without changing phone the system language settings, by only clicking in a button and then the application change the language without going through the settings.

Here is the code:

The Main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_darkmode/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
      supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en', "ZA"),
      Locale('pt', "MZ"),
      ],
      localizationsDelegates: [
      AppLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
       for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
        if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
            supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
          return supportedLocale;
          } else {
          if (MyHomePage.local != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < supportedLocales.length; i++) {
              if (MyHomePage.local == supportedLocales.elementAt(i)) {
                return supportedLocales.elementAt(i);
              }}}}}
            return supportedLocales.first;
            },
           home: MyHomePage(),
          );}

         class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
         @override
         _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

           class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
           getLocale() {
           Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
            print(myLocale);}

            @override
             Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              getLocale();
               return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                child: Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                   Text(
                   AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('first_string'),
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                   textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                  Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('second_string'),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('PT'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                     ),],),),),);}}
```

The app_locations class:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
final Locale locale;

  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
   return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

    static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate =
    _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

    Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;

       Future<bool> load() async {
       String jsonString =
        await rootBundle.loadString('lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');

        Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);

       _localizedStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
       return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
        });

        return true;}

       String translate(String key) {
      return _localizedStrings[key];}}

     class _AppLocalizationsDelegate
     extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
     const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

       @override
       bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
       return ['en', 'pt'].contains(locale.languageCode);}

       @override
       Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
       AppLocalizations localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
       await localizations.load();
       return localizations;}

        @override
        bool shouldReload(_AppLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;}
```

Comment: this may be helful for you,https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/03/flutter-localization-or-multi-language-example.html

Comment: I would recommend looking into the Get package: https://pub.dev/packages/get. Its internationalization support is quite robust and easy to use, you can read more here: https://pub.dev/packages/get#internationalization.
You can use the method described under "change locale" once your button is pressed to change the translations.

Comment: I would suggest this: https://medium.com/@puneetsethi25/flutter-internationalization-switching-locales-manually-f182ec9b8ff0

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can set the `locale` property of `MaterialApp` with your favourite state management method. For example:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();

  static _MyAppState of(BuildContext context) => context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Locale _locale;

  void setLocale(Locale value) {
    setState(() {
      _locale = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: _locale,
      home: Dashboard(),
    );
  }
}

class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Set locale to German"),
          onPressed: () => MyApp.of(context).setLocale(Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'de')),
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Set locale to English"),
          onPressed: () => MyApp.of(context).setLocale(Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'en')),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me! With a small modification: I could not get it to work when my FlutterApp had a StatfulWidget (eg MyApp) as the main 'home'. So I wrapped the stateful MyApp widget into a stateless widget (eg. MyAppWrapper). The only thing that the MyAppWrapper does is it has a build method that returns  MyApp().

Comment: but this wouldn't survive app restarts, would it?

Comment: @Marcus It does indeed not survive app restarts. You'd have to persist the data.

Comment: Any example that persists the changes

Comment: @LearnFlutter you could use the [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package and persist the data in there when the selection changes.

Then to read the data, you could do this:

`@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    SharedPreferencesHelper.getLanguageCode().then((languageCode) {
      setState(() {
        _locale = Locale(languageCode);
      });
    });

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }`

Comment: for some reasons I change the language in a different page and it that one works, but not when I come back. I need to refresh the app to see the full change

Comment: Great, it works! Many thanks also to Johannes Milke who provided the link to this solution in his comment here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIEegP0cUOQ&lc=UgyhH6RALB65y4UtX2R4AaABAg.9dsRVww65id9dv7RVJtgTy (maybe somebody is interested in this nice video also).

Answer (score 14):

You have to use Localizations given from Flutter. You have to use custom delegate and JSON files for your supported languages.
I implemented using `bloc`

Steps to follow,

1. Create a folder `assets/languages/` in the root folder
2. Create `JSON` files for your supported languages.
   Like: en.json, es.json
3. Create a key, value pairs for your strings in each file accordingly with their specific language strings
4. In `main.dart` create default `locale, supportedLocales and localizationsDelegates`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

import 'package:movie_app/common/constants/languages.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/presentation/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/presentation/blocs/language/language_bloc.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/presentation/journeys/home/home_screen.dart';

class MovieApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MovieAppState createState() => _MovieAppState();
}

class _MovieAppState extends State<MovieApp> {
  LanguageBloc _languageBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _languageBloc = LanguageBloc();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _languageBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<LanguageBloc>.value(
      value: _languageBloc,
      child: BlocBuilder<LanguageBloc, LanguageState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is LanguageLoaded) {
            return MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                title: 'Movie App',
                home: HomeScreen(),
                supportedLocales:
                    Languages.languages.map((e) => Locale(e.code)).toList(),
                locale: state.locale,
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  AppLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                ],
              );
          }
          return SizedBox.shrink();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

5. Now create Languages Language models and constants

```
class LanguageEntity {
  final String code;
  final String value;

  const LanguageEntity({
     this.code,
     this.value,
  });
}

class Languages {
  const Languages._();

  static const languages = [
    LanguageEntity(code: 'en', value: 'English'),
    LanguageEntity(code: 'es', value: 'Spanish'),
  ];
}
```

6. Now Create app localization delegate

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/common/constants/languages.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
  final Locale locale;

  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate =
      _AppLocalizationDelagate();

  static AppLocalizations of(context) =>
      Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);

  Map<String, String> _localisedString;

  Future<bool> load() async {
    final jsonString = await rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/languages/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    _localisedString =
        jsonMap.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
    return true;
  }

  String translate(String key) {
    return _localisedString[key];
  }
}

class _AppLocalizationDelagate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const _AppLocalizationDelagate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return Languages.languages
        .map((e) => e.code)
        .toList()
        .contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(covariant LocalizationsDelegate old) {
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppLocalizations appLocalizations = AppLocalizations(locale);
    await appLocalizations.load();
    return appLocalizations;
  }
}
```

7. Now create blocs

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
// import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/common/constants/languages.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/domain/entities/language_entity.dart';

part 'language_event.dart';
part 'language_state.dart';

class LanguageBloc extends Bloc<LanguageEvent, LanguageState> {
  LanguageBloc() : super(LanguageLoaded(Locale(Languages.languages[0].code)));

  @override
  Stream<LanguageState> mapEventToState(
    LanguageEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is ToggleLanguageEvent) {
      yield LanguageLoaded(Locale(event.language.code));
    }
  }
}
```

8.Now create event

```
part of 'language_bloc.dart';

abstract class LanguageEvent {
  const LanguageEvent();
}

class ToggleLanguageEvent extends LanguageEvent {
  final LanguageEntity language;

  ToggleLanguageEvent(this.language);
}
```

9. Now create state

```
part of 'language_bloc.dart';

abstract class LanguageState {
  const LanguageState();

}

class LanguageLoaded extends LanguageState {
  final Locale locale;

  LanguageLoaded(this.locale);
}
```

10.Now Create button to change languages.

```
RaisedButton(child: ,RaisedButton(child: Text('Switch', 
     onPressed: (int index) {
        BlocProvider.of<LanguageBloc>(context).add(
          ToggleLanguageEvent(
            Languages.languages[index], // index value can be 0 or 1 in our case
          ),                            // 0 - en, 1 - es
        );
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
);
```

Also, please refer the link for clear implementation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-2p3zB1z8k

Answer (score 9):

Because accepted answer has some shortcomings I will set new one:

Change locale of App can be done in several ways, here i will show two way:

**Way 1 (using `rxdart` and `SharedPreferences` plugins):**

For more understanding i was created project to explain how do that, you can find it in https://github.com/AnasSafi/flutter_localization_example

Output of project:

[image]

---

**Way 2:**

> Note 1: I was used [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin to save locale which
> client select.
>
> Note 2: Replace **ar** and **ps** with your default locale ...

Full code of **main.dart** file:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //To solve problem (ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized)
  runApp(MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  /*
  To Change Locale of App
   */
  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale newLocale) async {
    _MainAppState? state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MainAppState>();

    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('languageCode', newLocale.languageCode);
    prefs.setString('countryCode', "");

    state?.setState(() {
      state._locale = newLocale;
    });
    
  }

  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  Locale _locale = Locale('ar', 'ps');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this._fetchLocale().then((locale) {
      setState(() {
        this._locale = locale;
      });
    });
  }


  /*
  To get local from SharedPreferences if exists
   */
  Future<Locale> _fetchLocale() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String languageCode = prefs.getString('languageCode') ?? 'ar';
    String countryCode = prefs.getString('countryCode') ?? 'ps';

    return Locale(languageCode, countryCode);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: _locale,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        const FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate(),
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
        const Locale('ar', ''), // Arabic, no country code
      ],
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      home: InitializeApp(), // here use your own home name...
    );
  }
}


/*
  To solve problem of hold press on inputs
 */
class FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<CupertinoLocalizations> {
  const FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => true;

  @override
  Future<CupertinoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) =>
      DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.load(locale);

  @override
  bool shouldReload(FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

Now from any other class you need to change locale from it, you can use my way:

Import **main.dart** file, Then use my simple DropdownButton:

> Note: replace **value:
> AppLocalizations.of(context)!.locale.toString(),** this line with your
> way to get current locale of app...

```
import 'package:yout_project_name/main.dart';

DropdownButton(
  onChanged: (v) => setState(() {
    MainApp.setLocale(context, Locale(v.toString(), ""));
  }),
  value: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.locale.toString(), // change this line with your way to get current locale to select it as default in dropdown
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text( 'English'), value: 'en'
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text( 'العربية'), value: 'ar'
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using provider as state management then you can follow this article .

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the language_builder package in pub.dev
It is very easy to use. By wrapping your root widget with  LanguageBuilder you can configure your app's language.
Tell your app to use the phones' language or change it manually from the app.

https://pub.dev/packages/language_builder

Comment: Questions asking for resources are off-topic. This answer is only offering a link to a new resource, and doesn't show how to implement the resource to solve the question in the OP. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29942687)

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  /*
  To Change Locale of App
   */
  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale newLocale) async {
    _MainAppState? state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MainAppState>();

    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('languageCode', newLocale.languageCode);
    prefs.setString('countryCode', "");

    state?.setState(() {
      state._locale = newLocale;
    });
  }

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  Locale _locale = const Locale('ar', 'tn');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchLocale().then((locale) {
      setState(() {
        _locale = locale;
      });
    });
  }

  /*
  To get local from SharedPreferences if exists
   */
  Future<Locale> _fetchLocale() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String languageCode = prefs.getString('languageCode') ?? 'ar';
    String countryCode = prefs.getString('countryCode') ?? 'tn';

    return Locale(languageCode, countryCode);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: _locale,
      // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        const FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate(),
      ],
      // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
        const Locale('fr', ''),
        const Locale('ar', ''),
      ],
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      home: const AppContent(), // here use your own home name...
    );
  }
}

/*
  To solve problem of hold press on inputs
 */
class FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<CupertinoLocalizations> {
  const FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => true;

  @override
  Future<CupertinoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) =>
      DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.load(locale);

  @override
  bool shouldReload(FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate old) => false;
}

//___________________________________
class AppContent extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppContent({super.key});

  @override
  State<AppContent> createState() => _AppContentState();
}

class _AppContentState extends State<AppContent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.hello),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  MainApp.setLocale(context, const Locale("fr", ""));
                });
              },
              child: const Text("Fr"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  MainApp.setLocale(context, const Locale("en", ""));
                });
              },
              child: const Text("En"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  MainApp.setLocale(context, const Locale("ar", ""));
                });
              },
              child: const Text("Ar"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```